# Does Limewire, Baearshare etc have a database?

Tags: download, bittorrent, download-manager

I just found out that people are sharing songs that I created using programs called "Bearshare" and "Limewire". I always thought that these programs would search for music on thepiratebay, isohunt, kickasstorrents etc and display it in the program, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

So I'm wondering, how do these programs know where to look for my files? Is there a special database or just another torrent site that I didn't check?

Does Bearshare/Limewire even use the torrent protocol or is it something special?
I'm also wondering if there is a way to generate a torrent file out of a search result from these programs, so that I could try to search the internet for that file.

Answer (score 2):

Limewire does indeed support [Torrent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent) peer-to-peer networking as well as gnutella. Older versions of Bearshare support [gnutella](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnutella), later versions have a proprietary sharing service.

Both of these networks are fully distributed and do allow for searching without a central database. The two Wikipedia articles I've linked to contain a good starting point for understanding how the networks operate. So once shared, there is no realistic way to prevent it continuing without a significant amount of money available to do things like poisoning the files so people end up downloading rubbish. The MPAA and related organisations have made quite a few attempts at this.

---

I know you didn't ask about this part so feel free to ignore if not relevant:

If people are sharing your music, you have a number of options but worrying about the actual people doing the sharing is unlikely to help in any way other than sucking up a lot of money for solicitors.

If you feel that the the infringement is of very high value, then you could talk to a specialist lawyer but you are unlikely to really recover anything useful above the costs.

Alternatively, you could embrace what some progressive musicians are doing and reach out to fans instead of criminalising them. You might want to head over to the [Techdirt](http://www.techdirt.com) web site for some interesting ideas on that front.

Comment: "propitiatory" doesn't quite mean what you think. :)

Comment: ha ha! Actually it DOES! :) Spell check fubar!